# want to auto click cancel in prompt in firefox

Tags: greasemonkey

> OK so i currently play a game that has a random "bot-check" pop up in
>   the tab in the pop up it has a "OK" and "cancel" button and I'm trying
>   to find or make a grease monkey script to auto click "cancel" when it
>   pop's up and since its random it needs to be a always on type script

the prompt always shows up in the same x and y co-ordinates and button 1 is always OK and button 2 is always cancel hitting escape works just the same as hitting cancel

ive tried google and i cant find anything

Answer (score 0):

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js
$(".popup").bind('show',function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

may work, depends on the popup type.
if it doesn't work, try this:

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js
$(".popup").bind('show',function(){
    $(".popup .cancel).trigger("click");
});
```

[if JQuery wasn't successfully installed in your script previously, you'll need to uninstall your script and reinstall it]

**edit:** for imitation of pressing escape, use

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js
var esc = $.Event("keydown", {
keyCode: 27
});
$(".popup").bind('show',function(){
    $('body').trigger(esc);
});
```

Comment: is there anyway to add it to a script so if there is a interruption it auto hits ESC? im currently running a script on the page so modifying it would be cool

Comment: what do you mean by 'interruption'?

Comment: im trying the second option you suggested since the current script is running jquery already (http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/139347.html) is the one im running ATM, by interruption i mean when the pop up pops up but the script might possibly just spam enter non stop even when the pop up pops up

Comment: pop up is still coming up and nothing is happening i tried adding the editited one to its own greasemonkey script and to the existing one thats running as well as the other 2 suggested ones to their own greasemonkey scripts and its still stalling at the pop up