# Disabling a JavaScript or Jquery full screen overlay event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, greasemonkey

I am new here and wondering if someone can share some insight for me.

Lately I've been noticing that more websites are incorporating JavaScript or Jquery events that trigger a full screen overlay dialogue box. Some sites have the trigger based on time, scrolling patterns, login status, and even mouse focus within the webpage.

It has become a bit of a pet peeve of my own that I am being interrupted by what I feel is a popup 2.0. The only solution that I know is disabling JS all together in my browser, which in today's world is something that significantly degrades the operation of the website. A perfect example would be marketizator.com when the focus of the mouse leaves the body it will trigger the full screen overlay. Another example would be Twitter when you visit a profile without being logged in and are prompted to signup.

I'm wondering if someone can directly me to a way of how I can develop my own or discover an already existing method to prevent such events from being executed by websites within my own browser. Or even could someone identify the exact focus event that is being triggered.

My skills and knowledge level with JS is very little, but I am open to learning more to solve my problem.

Thanks for any help

Dave

Comment: Just install no script and be done with all the annoying sites in the world. Some site doesn't render well? Their competitors does.

Comment: Oh I do have NoScript / SafeScript, AdBlockers, and Ghosty installed. I find that each website has its own array of elements that can be equally annoying trying to prevent certain features from operating.

It seems like GreaseMonkey / Tampermonkey is the best way I can achieve my goal of nullifying the pesky overlay popups.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Chrome, Opera or Firefox - try http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/ extension. Install it, restart browser, click on its icon -> disable -> disable popups.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @lakesare, but after installing the extension to Chrome I still see the popup on marketizator.com when the mouse leaves the body. However, when visiting Twitter it does disable the popup.


So I'm halfway there. Anyone else have any idea what marketizator.com is using to trigger the popup event?

Comment: you can try greasemonkey, here is a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052042/want-to-auto-click-cancel-in-prompt-in-firefox/26052160#26052160. 'hide' solution will should work for marketizator.com.

Comment: I tried your solution and was not able to get it to work. How would I go about learning to modify your code to fit marketizator.com and any other website that behaves similarly?

Comment: hm, I don't think I understood what popup you were talking about then. in general - go to js console in developer's tools, play with the code and see what you need to execute to get rid of the pop up. if nothing obvious works, see what triggers the popup and insert js code that imitates your human close-popup behaviour on that event (press esc, press close). then just download 'user script manager' for your browser and try to implement your code.